# Is it possible to draw vertical separators in the interior gaps of a CSS grid of varying columns?

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to have a responsive grid of elements of variable length. The grid should fill the available width of the containing element, with the number of columns varying depending on the width of the container. This is straightforward to achieve using CSS grids; however, I don't know how to add a vertical border between columns (i.e., only in the interior column gaps). The below simple demo manages to achieve a vertical border in the event that there are three columns:

https://codepen.io/yowzadave/pen/OYPvLd?editors=1100

```css
html, body {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(24rem, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 0.5rem;
}

.item {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
}

.item:nth-child(3n) {
  border-right: none;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.box {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 2rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="item"><div class="box"></div></div>
      <div class="item"><div class="box"></div></div>
      <div class="item"><div class="box"></div></div>
      <div class="item"><div class="box"></div></div>
      <div class="item"><div class="box"></div></div>
      <div class="item"><div class="box"></div></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

...but in the event that the browser is wider or narrower, the borders will be misplaced. Is there a way to correctly place the borders at all browser widths?

Comment: If only [it had been done before](https://codepen.io/robleto/pen/EpGweR) 

Comment: @ChrisW. the solution you linked to has specific media queries that target either a two-column or three-column width. My question was about how to do this for a grid that could have an arbitrary number of columns depending on the container width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pseudo element on all the grid item where you will simply have overlap and be sure to cover all the gaps:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(15rem, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 0.5rem;
  overflow:hidden; /* Hide the overflow */
  position:relative;
}

.item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position:relative;
}

.item:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:-0.25rem; /* Half the gap */
  height:100vh; /* Big height*/
  width:1px;
  background:#000;
}

.box {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 2rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```