# Grid css selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a grid of 3 items per row. And I need to have lines between the items... I've been struggling with the :nth selectors but I can't get it working the correct way.

Maybe someone can help me with this?

See the image for a visual indication of what I need.

[image]

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/q/56012789/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- Make a grid using CSS grid
- Use `::after` to add a line after each box
- Use `::nth-child(3n)` to hide this `::after` line for every 3rd box (last box in the row) using `display:none`

I've written up a little example here:
https://codepen.io/annaazzam/pen/xxZPpXg

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it targeting each item except the last of a row and using a ::pseudo-element

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 6rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  background-color: #777;
  position: relative;
}

.item:not(:nth-child(3n))::after{
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 2px;
  right: -1rem;
  top: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

try this.

```css
hr{
  /and add some width and height and border to this /
}
```

```html
   <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
     <hr>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```